# Aplicar ROOM a un json de un servidor en android studio

Tags: android, json, kotlin, studio, room

Me gustaría saber si es posible utilizar ROOM para descargar un archivo json en android studio kotlin.
Quiero descargar un json de un servidor y después utilizarlo en android studio con un recycler view, es decir, que todos los items del json aparezca en mi recycler y que si se añade un nuevo item al json de servidor pueda actualizar mi aplicación

Sé que existe retrofit y que es una manera de hacerlo y que después podría aplicar ROOM pero el problema es que no tengo URL base, quiero decir, imaginaos que mi URL servidor/json/recetas.json
Pues bien, yo no puedo añadir a la URL /"nombre receta" y que me aparezca el item del json que estoy buscando por lo tanto retrofit no me sirve o bien no se aplicarlo

Ayuda por favor

Comment: Bienvenido, ¿Cuál es la duda en realidad?, al parecer preguntas varias cosas a la vez, te sugiero revisar [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el problema es que quieres añadir el nombre de una receta al `path` del json. Te dejo la [documentación de Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html) sobre como tendrías que hacer esto.

A modo de ejemplo, entiendo que sería algo así:
Tu función en tu servicio

```
@GET("servidor/json/recetas/{receta}")
suspend fun obtenerReceta(@Path("receta") receta: String): Response<Receta>
```